# In asp.net core API development I am adding connection string out from the auto generated dbcontext its throwing error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I created this connection string

[Picture of connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6yHy.png)

I used this command to generate sql connection string in the appsetting but its throwing this error =
[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52lNU.png)

The connection string I used is this =
Scaffold-DbContext -UseDatabaseNames = BookStoresDB Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models  - force

Comment: Please share error messages and code as text

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Command. I think it resolves your issue.

```
Scaffold-DbContext 'Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog= BookStoresDB' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir Data -OutputDir Models
```

For more details. [Click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) Here.

**UPDATE**

write the below code in your startup class in configureservice method.

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings")));
```

You have to obviously Create `ApplicationDbContext` class before update and migration your database.

`ApplicationDbContext.cs` looking like below code:-

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }



        //if you created a model and trying to use this
        public DbSet <YourModel> YourModelname{ get; set; }

    }
```

and then command `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` for that you successfully created a database. and you can use this as per your requirement.

Comment: Yes I did this way previously but I want to store the connection string in the appsetting and then I want to use that connection name on the dbcontext entity so how can I do that?

Comment: @CreativeWorld I updated my answer.please check